# Can not accept adWords managing invitation

Tags: google, google-ads

I just created new Google adWords manager account for being able to obtain adWords API access. For clarity purpose let's assume that the email associated with this account is *manager@gmail.com*.

After I created MCC I invited newly created manager from my initial (not manager's) account referred as let's say *user@gmail.com* - this invitation appeared on my page:

[image]

However I don't see any invitations in my manager's account:

[image]

In the manager's inbox *manager@gmail.com* appeared an email regarding the invitation with a link to confirm. If I use the link provided I'm getting unexpected page asking me if I'd like to use any present account or to create a new one (which is weird). If I try to put manager's email (*manager@gmail.com*) in the box below I will get this:

[image]

So it looks like Google tries me to create new account which I don't need actually as I already have two: regular (*user@gmail.com*) and manager's (*manager@gmail.com*).

Any thoughts why the invitation not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I've done thing in a wrong way. Instead of inviting manager from managing account I should request access TO managing account (*user@gmail.com*) FROM manager's account by managing account (*manager@gmail.com*) NUMBER.

After I did all these things I linked accounts and now I was able to apply for API token.

Thank you all for participation!

Comment: Right, @JosipIvic. Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: no, it's ok, but in my personal opinion, it's nonsense.

Comment: @JosipIvic, It is nonsense in this particular question or generally? What should I do in your opinion if I did find the answer by my self? Not post the answer at all? Or avoid accepting it just for a reason this was my answer? My opinion is that the way I done is the best for someone facing with the same problem as I was. Anyway: English isn't my native language so I suppose that you probably find my comment a kind of aggressive (it wasn't intended to be) and my question and answer a bit unclear. I have to say sorry for that. If you have any opinion I asked above - please comment!

Answer (score 3):

As what @Josip Ivic pointed out, One Google account means for all Google features - If you log in to your adsense account, you will see in `settings` menu about other products of google and there you can sync your adsense account to Adwords, Mob, etc. This is clear I hope.

In related to `Access Account` in Adwords is used when you would like to invite "someone else" which has no related to your current account (different `......@gmail.com`) to be your contributor to manage your adwords (as administrative access).

Answer (score 2):

Mail was registered once to adwords. And it still is. And as part of google policy, you can't link your account to new adsense account because you have one already linked to that mail.

Comment: Which mail you're talking about? Managers? I realized what the page shown on the last screen shot wanted from me. And this was unexpected for me. I put some clarification to the initial question. Please review and I will be appreciate if any additional comments will follow.